# Return nodes with and without a relation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi I'm very new to Cypher Syntax and need some help!

I want to write a query that return all "a" with relation to "b" and all "a" that doesn't have a relation with "b" so I can return every "a" and only "b" with relation to "a".

What I want to do

```
 match (a:TypeA)-[r]->(b:TypeB) 
 match (a:TypeA) 
 return a, b
```

What I don't want to do

```
 match (a1:TypeA)-[r]->(b:TypeB) 
 match (a2:TypeA)
 return a1, a2, b
```

Is there a way to do this or is my only option to go for the second query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional match is what you're looking for:

MATCH (a:TypeA)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r]->(b:TypeB)
RETURN a, b

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/optional-match/

Answer (score 0):

This query will return each `TypeA` in a separate row, along with a (possibly empty) list of `TypeB` end nodes:

```
MATCH (a:TypeA) 
RETURN a, [(a)-->(b:TypeB) | b] AS bs
```